# displaying content of other table in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two tables `Operational_area` and `Compliance` with `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship.

In `Operational_Area` index page I want to fetch `Compliance_Name`, but in my `operational_area` table I have only `compliance_id`.

How can I fetch the `compliance_name` here.

My controller is:

```
  index do
    column :id
    column :weightage
    column :compliance_id

    actions
  end
```

when I'm using

```
        column :compliance_id
```

I'm getting empty colomn in my view page.

Comment: Post your index page.

Comment: and also, could you provide us with your models exact relationships ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using delegates

```
delegate :name, to: :compliance
```

This will allow you to call 'name' directly on operational_area as:

```
<%= operational_area.name %>
```